# Delphi: How to get Application.MainForm if the Application is nil (in dll)

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

I need the main form of the application to perform `ClientToParent()` and unsuccessful because I'm in a dll and the Application variable is nil. I appreciate anybody's help.

Comment: Are you trying to access the calling process' application main form? Or a form which you have inside the DLL? DLL's have no knowledge of its calling process, it doesn't even know what programming language it was made in, let alone what kind of application it is.

Comment: @Jerry DLLs don't have "calling proceesses". They are loaded into a process. A DLL does indeed know about the process it lives in.

Comment: @David My point was the DLL has no knowledge about object structures, etc. The DLL doesn't even know if its host process is VCL, FMX, or .NET/C#. Not that it's impossible to detect it, but that's just the nature of DLL's, they're not supposed to know those kinds of things (unless the developer has that goal to).

Comment: @Jerry I'd use the term application for that. Process is a lower level term and DLLs know plenty about their host process.

Comment: @David Yes, Application, point taken. I'm horrible with terminology, and in general putting the proper names on things (and even people). Takes hearing someone's name at least 20 times before I remember it... I've barely put thought to the difference between an Application and a Process which seem like the same thing but I do know they are not.

Comment: Export a function that would take a handle and calculate your point with api calls, like MapWindowPoints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do anything with a form reference across a module boundary. The host application, even assuming it is a Delphi application, has a different instance of the VCL. So you cannot use a `TForm` instance from the app in the DLL. You could do so if you were using packages.

You could perhaps enumerate top level windows and find the one in your process. That could work but is messy.

Far better would be to expose functionality to allow the host to provide such services. When the host loaded your DLL it would supply an interface which provided the necessary services. It could convert the coordinates as you need, and perhaps offer other services.

One thing I would query though is that you intend to call `ClientToParent`. This suggests that you have client/parent relationships between controls in different modules. That is only viable if you are using packages. I do wonder whether you are fully aware of the restrictions relating to VCL usage across modules.